# When and how to call a javascript function which looks for page scrolling action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-pagescroller

I have written a code to look for page scrolling. It works when I put it inside script tag. 
How to put this code inside a function and let it look for page scrolls?

Here is my code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
                if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                    alert('scrolling');
                }
});
```

Comment: It should be the same?

Comment: "It works when I put it inside script tag", where else do you want to put it? It always will go in a script tag.

Comment: @abimelex Doesn't have to be. What should be the general approach for such a scenario?

Comment: @albanx I want it to be a part of function inside script tag

Comment: You are doing a bind on window. I will advice doing a separate js file. See me answer now...

Answer (score 2):

I did not understand exactly what you ask,something like this ? (put this in a script tag or an external js file)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function(e){
         detect_scrollPage(e);
    });

});

function detect_scrollPage(event){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Question was, is it possible to have a user defined function which keeps it self busy looking for page scrolls?

Comment: this function (detect_scrollPage) , will be called each time the page is scrolled

Comment: @PrathviRaj If you had a JavaScript function that "kept itself busy", your page would likely be unusable. There's no reason to try to implement the check for yourself, just use the scroll events handled by the browser.

Comment: @PrathviRaj if you need a global function that handles all scrolls in the page this is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
function scrollBinder(selector, callback){
    $(selector).scroll(function(e){
         callback.call(this, e);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    scrollBinder('#some_div', function(div, event) {
        //do calcl here
    })

    //or on window
    scrollBinder(window, function(div, event) {
        //do calcl here
    })

});
```

Any way it is a shorthand, most people will do that the same as you did.